# MDI form is beneath the buttons

Tags: c#

```
Form3 newMDIChild = new Form3();
        newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
        newMDIChild.Show();
```

I want to create Mdi form and to do this but Mdichild form under the first form button.  [just like that](https://ibb.co/cKKNF5)
I want Form 3 to be at the top.
how can i fix it?

Comment: generally, as a rule of style, I don't put controls onto the MDI parent.

Comment: You need to **Dock** a **Panel** in your MdiParent, then add those Buttons to the Panel.  The MdiChild will then be in the space left over and not over the Buttons.

Comment: Idle_Mind gave you the exact answer. Don't forget to hook up the buttons. Note that the original layout wouldn't leave any space for the childform. Also note that the childform __can't_ overlap the controls on the parentform so maybe the answer is: 'can't be done'!
`Form f1 = new Form();
f1.IsMdiContainer = true;
Panel p1 = new Panel();
p1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
p1.Parent = f1;
Button b1 = new Button();
b1.Parent = p1;
Form f2 = new Form();
f2.MdiParent = f1;
f1.Show();
f2.Show();`